# Coloring Nodes of a NumPy Matrix

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm a beginner python programmer, could someone help me?
I have a graph file, I am trying to store it in a matrix and color each node a different color than each adjacent node, but I'm getting an error:
Please see associated files at this [file link](//drive.google.com/drive/folders/1SDhczl_fTwH4zt31XEVna_0ocXxPF4C6) where you can see logs etc.

```
import re
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def get_instances(chemin):
  p = [] # pour recup p
  f = open(chemin, "r")
  g = []
  for x in f:
    g.append(x)
  for i in g:
    if i.startswith('p'):
      p.append(i) 
      nb_noeud = int(" ".join(p).split(' ',3)[2])
      nb_arret = int(" ".join(p).split(' ',3)[3])
      # p edge 32 10

  e = [] # pour recup e
  for i in g:
    if i.startswith('e'): 
      e.append(i)
  c1 = []
  c2  =[]
  for l in range(len(e)):
    c1.append([int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', e[l])][0])
    c2.append([int(s) for s in re.findall(r'\b\d+\b', e[l])][1])

  c= {'c1':c1, "c2":c2}
  mat = pd.DataFrame(data=c).to_numpy()
  return nb_arret, nb_noeud, mat

nb_arret,nb_noeud,new_mat = get_instances('/content/DSJC125.9.col.txt')

nb_arret

nb_noeud

new_mat=np.asmatrix(new_mat)
new_mat

# Python3 program for the above approach

# Number of vertices in the graph
# check if the colored graph is safe or not
new_mat=np.asmatrix(new_mat)

graph=new_mat
def isSafe(graph, color):
    # check for every edge
    for i in range(len(graph)):
        for j in range(i, len(graph)):
            if (graph[i][j] and color[j] == color[i]):
                return False
    return True

def graphColoring(graph, m, i, color):
    # if current index reached end
    if (i == 100):
        # if coloring is safe
        if (isSafe(graph, color)):
            # Print the solution
            printSolution(color)
            return True
        return False

    # Assign each color from 1 to m
    for j in range(1, m + 1):
        color[i] = j
        # Recur of the rest vertices
        if (graphColoring(graph, m, i + 1, color)):
            return True
        color[i] = 0
    return False

# /* A utility function to print solution */
def printSolution(color):
    print("Solution Exists:" " Following are the assigned colors ")
    for i in range(100):
        print(color[i], end=" ")

# Driver code
if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = 100 # Number of colors

    # Initialize all color values as 0.
    # This initialization is needed
    # correct functioning of isSafe()
    color = [0 for i in range(100)]

    # Function call
    if (not graphColoring(graph, m, 0, color)):
        print("Solution does not exist")
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-1255ddf6bad1> in <module>
     83 
     84         # Function call
---> 85         if (not graphColoring(graph, m, 0, color)):
     86                 print("Solution does not exist")
     87 

101 frames
<ipython-input-48-1255ddf6bad1> in isSafe(graph, color)
     15         for i in range(len(graph)):
     16                 for j in range(i, len(graph)):
---> 17                         if (graph[i][j] and color[j] == color[i]):
     18                                 return False
     19         return True

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `or` or `and` -> use `|` or `&` respectively (when working with pandas)

Reason: `or` or `and` require truth-values. Whereas with pandas objects (Series in your case) are considered ambiguous so you should use `|` (or) or `&` (and) bitwise operations

Comment: still facing the same error